# Implications of adding empty implementations to satisfy proc macro generation

Tags: rust

Lets say I have a trait `ShowStrings` with a method `show_strings`. Calling `show_strings` will deeply find `String`s and print them out (with `println!()`).

The trait has a accompanying derive macro for it which traces all the fields of a structure and generates the recursive calls.

So for example the structure `struct Person { first_name: String, last_name: String, children: Vec<Person>, height: f32 }`, `Person::show_strings` will print out their first and last name and then recurse to do the same for their children.

The trait `ShowStrings` implementation on `String` is to print out self.

The question I have is what to do about the `height: f32` field. `f32` is not a string neither does it have any fields that can be strings. There are two options for how to handle `ShowStrings` for `f32`:

Either the proc derive macro generates a `ShowStrings::show_strings(self.height)` call **and** `f32` gets a blank implementation: `impl ShowStrings for f32 { fn show_strings(&self) {} }`

Or the proc macro sees the `f32` type reference and decides to ignore that field.

The first method is what the [gc crate does](https://github.com/Manishearth/rust-gc/blob/master/gc/src/trace.rs#L118). This can be automated with a simple macro so is not too manual. It would mean `ShowStrings` would be implemented on something like `()` which doesn't make sense and could confuse users of the API. Also I would assume Rust would compile away the call `ShowStrings::show_string(field_that_has_empty_implementation)` so it would not call/jump.

The second method ends up with less generated code. But type references are weak as they can be shadowed, the [type name may have been shadowed](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=3e9e853b1264b2226f54d161897113ef).

I think I will go for the first method? Are there any performance, binary size or other concerns around having lots of implementations that are empty? `impl MyTrait for *inbuilt_type* { fn func() {} }`